# position absolute is not working

Tags: html, css

How can I set the div `#gallery` in the center of the div `#warp`? Here is a [demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/ZY7Dv/2/).

HTML:

```
<div id="warp">
    <div id="header">
        <img id="logo_l" src="images/centerwow-logo.png" alt="Centerwow - Web Design - Logo" />
        <img id="Logo_r" src="images/web-design-logo.png" alt="centerwow.com - Portfolio" title="Portfolio" >
        <div id="menu">
            <li><a href="#"  title="About Us">About Us</a>
            <li><a href="#" name="aboutus" title="About Us" >Company Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="profile"  title="Profile" > Profile</a></li>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div id="gallery"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    background:#F7F7F7;
}

#warp{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#header {
        position:relative;
        background:#DEEAF4;
        width:80%;
        height: 100px;
        margin:0 auto;

    }
#logo_l{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

#Logo_r{
    position:absolute;
    width:272px ;
    height:100px;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}    

#menu li {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    }

#menu {
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    top: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    }
#gallery{
    position:absolute;
    background:#EBF0F5;
    width:80%;
    height:70%;
    margin:10px auto;
    padding:10px;
}    
​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to include `position: absolute` to center `#gallery`. This will already be achieved with `margin: 10px auto`.

Further, to set a percentage height to `#gallery`, its parent element must have a specific height. In this case, I assume you want it to be based on viewport height. To do so, every ancestor div must have a height of 100%:

```
*, html, body, #warp {
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qc9WL/1/

NOTE: I also noticed that there are some bugs in your HTML and CSS.

- You need a comma between `body` and `html` in line one of your style sheet
- You should use `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags when making lists
- Lastly, don't forget to close your `<li>` in line six

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here - `position: absolute` on the `#gallery` is exactly what's causing the problem (that's why `margin: 10px auto` is not working). If you remove it, the `#gallery` element will be in the centre.

Also, you could center horizontally an absolutely positioned element of known width by setting  `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: -40%;` (-40% in this case, because you have the width for `#gallery` set to 80%)

Comment: I don't think it can work. `height: 70%` in this case means 70% of the height of the `#warp` element, whose height is not explicitly specified => it is computed based on the heights of its relative children, `#gallery` being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying gallery width in percentage, why don't you try setting the left and right margin in percentage?

```
margin: 10px 10%;
```

places the division at center